# Scrum Training Sheet for new teams

Tags: scrum, scrum-master

**Question:**  What quick reference, training, items about Scrum need to be on a training sheet for quick reference to keep everyone in the know about what Scrum is, its processes and common terminology?

**Basis:**  I am new to Scrum, and project management, and will be taking on the roll of Scrum Master.  The Product Owner knows nothing about Scrum other than a brief 30 minute Q/A about the roll of Product Owner and what was entailed.  The team also knows nothing about Scrum and will be relying on me to help them through the process of it all.

I have some basic ideas at this point as to what should go on such a sheet.  Nothing fancy, not too much information.  Just something that someone could look at and have a general grasp and understanding within 30 seconds to 1 minute worth of time.

**What I have so far**

**[edit]** [To make things simpler of what I have implemented I am sharing the doc through Google Docs](http://goo.gl/TNU7R).

[image]

[**Edit**] - I am using the book Agile Software Development with Scrum.
We value individuals and interactions over processes and tools... Asking a team to read a document is the process, the document is the tool.  I believe that the tool can be condensed to portray the required information that is most pertinent to scrum. Providing further resources and materials on specifics of course should always be made available (transparency), however even so most people only read in depth what is pertinent to them and what they are interested in.

I am asking what is the absolute basics that are needed to gain an overview understanding of what Scrum is to be condensed into a single sheet of paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked the [Scrum RefCard](https://web.archive.org/web/20130901040809/http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/scrum) from DZone?

Comment: Exactly! Besides, there are several other interesting RefCardz in this same website...

Comment: The stupid thing is, I have used that site so many times in the past and didn't even think to check. =D Regardless awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The Scrum guide is what you need. You can find it [here](http://www.scrum.org/Scrum-Guides). Everyone on the team should read it.

There really isn't anything that you could look at to grasp Scrum in 30 seconds, other than the statement:

Scrum is about decreased cycle times and increased communication, facilitated by self organizing teams and constant feedback loops.

Comment: While I understand that a reference sheet is not going to ever go into enough detail to allow someone the ability to fully grasp in full detail the amount of information needed to know any learning material in a single read.  I do believe that 16 pages or more is too much information as a reference sheet for quick reference and guidelines.  I really like your statement of what scrum is ^_^  Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [Intro to Agile Scrum in Under 10 minutes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_650246&feature=iv&src_vid=Q5k7a9YEoUI&v=XU0llRltyFM) video that does a decent job.

Also, I'd try the [Wikipedia page on Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) - it's actually quite good.

You can start with those, but 30 seconds to 1 minute is a pretty tough task, and I'd say you should be able to ask people on the team to spend more time than that to learn the new development process.

Comment: Haha, Yeah.  I think I have been giving the wrong impression.  Part of the problem is some of the team members are Artists that are a bit flighty and ADD/ADHD so it is difficult to actually keep their attention for longer than 5 minutes, though they pretend well enough after, are not really paying attention.  I had already been referencing the wiki of course.  My main intention isn't to give an all inclusive of course, just enough information in a quick enough spurt that when going into further detail about certain items, such as specific responsibilities, that no one is completely lost.

Comment: Hey Jody, do you think you might be able to summarize the video and quote the relevant parts of the Wiki article? In general, we try to make sure answers are self contained and use links as an extra "for further reading, see <link>". I think if you at least summarize the Wiki article that would be awesome! Good luck!

Comment: Did you just describe some of your team members as flighty and having ADD? Maybe you should think about the way you treat your team members. If I saw this online, I would be quite upset. Seriously, you need to rethink how you treat people.

Comment: @aclear16 One artist is my fiance, the other artist is a long term friend.  Both of which would laugh and say "Yeaaah!" to my comment, and have poked fun at themselves for that very comment before I even thought to use it.  I do appreciate the concern for not speaking poorly about individuals online or offline, I hope the context gives clarity to the comment.

Comment: Private discourse and public discourse are two entirely different things. This is a persistent, publicly searchable format that you just included what could be construed as derogatory information about team members. What if they are searching for a new job, and you are listed as their previous PM? Oh, and ADD and ADHD are separate medical conditions. Throwing them around is either 1) a gross invasion of your teammates privacy or 2) horribly inaccurate. I see your point perfectly well in a private context, but this is not private. Please treat public forums as public.